# How to resolve unhandled exception? (OpenGL, GLFW3)

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, cursor-position

The exception says:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00F52157 in Foundry.exe: 0xC0000005: access violation reading location 0x00000030.

and points to this line in controls.cpp:

```
glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);
```

Controls code in separate file controls.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
extern GLFWwindow* window;
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
using namespace glm;

#include "controls.hpp"

glm::mat4 ViewMatrix;
glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix;

glm::mat4 getViewMatrix(){
return ViewMatrix;
}
glm::mat4 getProjectionMatrix(){
return ProjectionMatrix;
}

glm::vec3 position = glm::vec3( 0, 0, 5 ); 
float horizontalAngle = 3.14f;
float verticalAngle = 0.0f;
float initialFoV = 45.0f;
float speed = 3.0f;
float mouseSpeed = 0.005f;



void computeMatricesFromInputs(){

  static double lastTime = glfwGetTime();
  double currentTime = glfwGetTime();
  float deltaTime = float(currentTime - lastTime);

  double  xpos;
  double    ypos;

  glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);
  glfwSetCursorPos(window, 1280/2, 1024/2);

  horizontalAngle += mouseSpeed * float (1280/2 - xpos );
  verticalAngle   += mouseSpeed * float (1024/2 - ypos );

  glm::vec3 direction(
    cos(verticalAngle) * sin(horizontalAngle), 
    sin(verticalAngle),
    cos(verticalAngle) * cos(horizontalAngle)
  );

  glm::vec3 right = glm::vec3(
    sin(horizontalAngle - 3.14f/2.0f), 
    0,
    cos(horizontalAngle - 3.14f/2.0f)
  );

  glm::vec3 up = glm::cross( right, direction );

  if (glfwGetKey( window, GLFW_KEY_UP || GLFW_KEY_W ) == GLFW_PRESS){
    position += direction * deltaTime * speed;
  }

  if (glfwGetKey( window, GLFW_KEY_DOWN || GLFW_KEY_S ) == GLFW_PRESS){
    position -= direction * deltaTime * speed;
  }

  if (glfwGetKey( window, GLFW_KEY_RIGHT || GLFW_KEY_D ) == GLFW_PRESS){
    position += right * deltaTime * speed;
  }

  if (glfwGetKey( window, GLFW_KEY_LEFT || GLFW_KEY_A ) == GLFW_PRESS){
    position -= right * deltaTime * speed;
  }

  float FoV = initialFoV;
  ProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(FoV, 5.0f / 4.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
  ViewMatrix       = glm::lookAt(position,position+direction,up);

  lastTime = currentTime;
}
```

The program works well without matrices being modified by input controls.

To be honest, I don't know much about low level programming and memory allocation, so this might be the cause.

Comment: Use a debugger and check where it's thrown, then fix the code there! I can't spot what `window` actually is, and if you initialized it correctly BTW.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you for the point. `GLFWwindow* window` was initialized incorrectly in main source code. Specifically, two times: globally and locally. I just forgot to remove second initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is memory access violation not exception that you get there.

That `window` is likely bad pointer when matrices are computed. Somewhere in your code is result of `glfwCreateWindow()` assigned to that `window`. Is it done before computing the matrices? Does this result with not `NULL` value?  there may be `glfwDestroyWindow(window);` somewhere in your code. If so is it done after computing the matrices?

Comment: The issue was that `GLFWwindow* window` was initialized incorrectly in main source code. Specifically, two times: globally and locally, so control functions were not able to access the window.